# Disable the label text (min, max, average, bins values) in measure annotation while doing MeasureX in highstocks and highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am rather new to highcharts and highstocks  and that is why I am not able to figure out what is it that I am doing wrong in order to disable the text (min, max, average, bins values)  which appears in the annotation when we do MeasureX using stockTools. All i want to do is not show the user these values in the annotation an sather have an empty and clear annotation. I am doing this with below code but I am getting **"Can not read property X of undefined"**. I am not sure where is this undefined coming from.

```
annotations: [{
            type: 'measure',
            typeOptions: {
                label: {
                    enabled: false
                }

            }
        }],
```

Want to not show the encircled area.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the label through `navigation.bindings`, example:

```
navigation: {
  bindings: {
    measureXY: {
      annotationsOptions: {
        typeOptions: {
          label: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8nxj9v6k/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigation.bindings.measureXY

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek, It seems to be working for me. But I am still not able to understand that what was wrong with my solution? I have picked up that solution from the Highcharts API reference itself. And the solution that you have provided although it is working for me but I can not find an API refrence for that. In measureXY only start and steps event is given and not the typeoptions.

Comment: Hi @Nishit, As you can see the `annotations` option is an array and it is used to directly add annotations to a chart, not to set options for all annotations. The `annotationsOptions` property has the same options as: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/annotations.measure